# Inserting new item to instance variable in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**@xs** stores urls like www.yahoo.com, www.google.com

```
for x in @xs
     y = x... #do something with x
     @result += y  #i want to do something like that. i want to store them in @result. What do i have to write in here?
end
```

Sorry for noob question. By the way how do you call @result ? Is it an instance variable or an array ?

Comment: @result will be overwritten per iteration - i don't think thats how you wanna do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `@result` first.

```
@result = []
for x in @xs
  y = x...
  @result << y
end
```

Comment: @result = Array.new That was the problem. Thanks. Also other answers worked too.

Answer (score 1):

You should either do this:

```
@result << y
```

or this:

```
@result += [y]
```

The `+` operator expects two arrays, the `<<` operator appends an object onto an array.

Comment: It should be the first one if you want to mutate the array. `+=` will create a new array with `y` at the end and set the `@result` variable to that new array.

Comment: when i tried first one. It says 
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<

Answer (score 1):

From what I can make out from the question, you want to mutate the contents of the already existing array

```
@mutated_xs = @xs.collect do |x|
  y = x.do_something # some code for to do something to x returning y
  x += y # mutate existing x here
end
puts @mutated_xs.inspect
```

Comment: This is what I would think he meant too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take every element in an array and change it, the idiomatic Ruby way is to use map or collect:

```
@new_urls = @urls.map do |url|
  # change url to its new value here
end
```

You don't need to manually assign it to @new_urls, just write a statement that returns the desired value, like `url.upcase` or whatever you want to do.